# Iteration over XML returns Same Node Over & Over

Tags: c#, xml, iteration, xmlnode

The following is supposed to generate a list of all messages.

In practice I get a list of the rought length, but with the same element over and over.

`Message` is a class that get populated from the XmlNode sent to the constructor.

```
_messages = new List<Message>();
/*This does it*/
foreach (XmlNode n in thread.SelectNodes("//messages/message"))
{
    _messages.Add(new Message(n));
}
/*So does this*/
XmlNode msgItr = thread.SelectSingleNode("//messages").FirstChild;
while (msgItr != null)
{
    _messages.Add(new Message(msgItr));
    msgItr = msgItr.NextSibling;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe problem is in XML part of the code. Please make sure to update post that shows *small* XML sample and relatively complete version of the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Side note: I assume that you do understand that `"//"` in XPath is "starting from the root give me all nodes...." and not "staring from the current node give me all nodes ..." - that would be good reason to close as typographical error.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you check the results of `SelectNodes` to ensure that you actually get unique results (I expect you will). If all `Message` instances appear the same, could it be that they store the same data, eg in a static field?

Comment: try this :             XmlNode messages = thread.SelectSingleNode("//messages");
            foreach(XmlElement message in messages.SelectNodes("message"))
            {
                _messages.Add(new Message(message));
            }

Comment: We need to see an instanceof your document.

Comment: Try to use `.//` instead of `//` for relative xpath.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I assumed that it takes the current node as root, since I've put it in a seperate object

Comment: Though it shouldn't really matter for the document we're working on

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, of course, I did check, the list has the unique values, but the iteration doesn't show that

Comment: @JNF Post the code of the Message class. A sample of the XML would help so we can repro this (or not), but I suspect you are either storing the data in a static field inside Message, or extracting an attribute that stays the same.

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. Thanks to the comments, espcially @AlexeiLevenkov, I realized that in the Message object the properties look like this: `return _message.SelectSingleNode("//subject").LastChild.Value;`, which always returned the nodes of the same message. Thanks to all. Using `./subject` solved the problem.

Comment: Problem solved, wasn't related to question.

Comment: @JNF feel free to close the question than (or find duplicate if you want to keep it). Side note: If you working with XML I'd recommend to come up with a way to read XPath aloud - helps a lot to hear what you wrote. I.e. pronouncing each XPath step like following worked for me: "//message[@type='foo']/subject" - "start from root - *find all* `message` nodes - *where* there is *attribute*  `type` - *with* value 'foo' - than select *immediate* child 'subject' node".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks. I voted to close, but it takes more than one...

Answer (score 0):

You are pathing to the wrong location, just use `//message`.

Here is two ways of enumerating the nodes, I am using LinqPad which `Dump()` shows one the current state.

```
XDocument xd = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Messages",   
         new XElement("Message", "Alpha"),
         new XElement("Message", "Beta"),
         new XElement("Message", "Omega")
  ));

  xd.Descendants("Message").Dump("XDocument");

  XmlDocument xmd = new XmlDocument();

  xmd.LoadXml(xd.ToString());

  xmd.SelectNodes("//Message")
     .Dump("XmlDocument");
```

Here is the results for the first and second dumps

[image]

Comment: There is no difference between using `//Messages/Message` and `//Message`. Using your own code, //Messages/Message` will return the same results as those you posted